# Why is button not moved as expected

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a view controller which needs to be laid out differently between landscape and portrait.  The following code works almost perfectly except for one small thing.  In the case of the button that is moved (the one with the tag=3), when I click on the other button (which has tag=0 and invokes (IBAction)myButton: ) the button moves to the position where it was put in the storyboard.  The label doesn't move, just the button.  This only happens if the value of the title being set in (IBAction)myButton is different from its value before the button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *but2 = (UIButton * )[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    [but2 setTitle: @"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UILabel *lab =(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    lab.text=@"B";
}
-(void)rotateViewToPortrait{
    UIButton *but2 = (UIButton * )[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    [but2 setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 500, but2.frame.size.width, but2.frame.size.height)];
    UILabel *lab =(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    [lab setFrame:CGRectMake(100,550 , lab.frame.size.width, lab.frame.size.height)];
}
-(void)rotateViewToLandscape{
    UIButton *but2 = (UIButton * )[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    [but2 setFrame:CGRectMake(500, 100 , but2.frame.size.width, but2.frame.size.height)];
    UILabel *lab =(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    [lab setFrame:CGRectMake(500,150 , lab.frame.size.width, lab.frame.size.height)];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if ((orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)||(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight duration:0];
    } else {
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait duration:0];
    }
}
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)||(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {
        [self rotateViewToLandscape];
    } else if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)||(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
    [self rotateViewToPortrait];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cured the problem by turning off AutoLayout in the view controller in the storyboard.  I also removed all springs and struts and turned off Autoresize subviews in the main view.
I'm still not sure why the behaviour was as described as above.  But hey-ho it works now.

Comment: Upvoted— this solved my problem instantly. I had a view that wasn't using any constraints but the xib had "Use Auto Layout" checked, and its subviews' positions were offset in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

This code:

```
if (howManyButtons==2) {
    button1.hidden=true;
    button2.hidden=false;
    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(177,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
    button3.hidden=false;
    [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(703,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
    button4.hidden=true;
} else {
    button1.hidden=false;
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(71,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
    button2.hidden=false;
    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(317,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
    button3.hidden=false;
    [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(563,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
    button4.hidden=false;
    [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(809,button2.frame.origin.y,button2.frame.size.width,button2.frame.size.height)];
}
```

When (howManyButtons==2), if the images on the buttons had been loaded with code like this:

```
    UIImage *btnImage4 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [button4 setImage:btnImage4  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the buttons moved as expected, but when the images on the buttons had been loaded with this code (to get image from iPad's photo library instead of a resource in the app itself):

```
NSURL *testURL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:[self albumNameForPic:albumNo picNo:[self picNoForAlbum:albumNo picNo:picNo]]];
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary assetForURL:testURL resultBlock: ^(ALAsset *asset){

    CGImageRef imageRef = [asset thumbnail];

    if (imageRef) {
        switch (buttonNo) {
            case 1:
                [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 2:
                [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 3:
                [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            case 4:
                [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // Handle failure.
}];
```

the buttons didn't move, they stayed where they were set to be in Main.storyboard.

I'm guessing the difference in behaviour is down to the fact that the Asset Library code to set the button images is run asynchronously .....

Turning off AutoLayout solved the problem but, like Popeye, I don't understand why (which I don't like).